# Error with simple extension to Chrome, in console message : "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just wrote this simple plugin to Chrome that have to change a single letter in all words on page. However, I still have problem with connectivity between popup.js and contentScript.js (in console at web search I have a message: "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist".

The code of my program is below.

```
//manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "name": "Word Changer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Word Changer",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/edit.png",
      "48": "assets/edit.png",
      "128": "assets/edit.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
//popup.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Zmieniacz Słów</title>
  <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'nonce-RANDOM_NONCE'">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Word changer</h2>

  <input type="text" id="letterToReplace" value="r"/>
  <input type="text" id="newLetter" value="X"/>
  <button id="myButton">Change</button>

  <script nonce="RANDOM_NONCE" type="module" src="chrome-extension://ojkemfjfmjmpbnfdcbbplgkiaelfdbie/popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//popup.js

 const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
    const letterToReplaceInput = document.getElementById("letterToReplace");
    const newLetterInput = document.getElementById("newLetter");

    myButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const letterToReplace = letterToReplaceInput.value;
        const newLetter = newLetterInput.value;

        chrome.tabs.query({ 
            active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            try {
                var activeTab = tabs[0];
                console.log("Sending message");
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {
                    action: "changeLetter",
                    letterToReplace: letterToReplace,
                    newLetter: newLetter
                  }, window.onload = function(response) { 
                        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                        } else {
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    }
                );
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error sending message:", error);
            }
        });
    });
```

```
//contentScript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("Message received");
    if (request.action === "changeLetter") {
    //const wordToChange = request.word;
    const letterToReplace = request.letter;
    const newLetter = request.newLetter;

    const modifiedWord = changeLetterInWord(wordToChange, letterToReplace, newLetter);

    replaceTextInBody(document.body, wordToChange, modifiedWord);
  }else{
    console.log("Unknown action");
  }
});

function replaceTextInBody(element, searchTerm, replacement) {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    const node = element.childNodes[i];

    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      
      const replacedText = node.textContent.replace(new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi"), replacement);
      node.textContent = replacedText;
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      // Jeśli to jest element, wywołaj rekurencyjnie dla jego dzieci
      replaceTextInBody(node, searchTerm, replacement);
    }
  }
}

function changeLetterInWord(word, letterToReplace, newLetter) {
  const wordArray = word.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    if (wordArray[i] === letterToReplace) {
      wordArray[i] = newLetter;
    }
  }
  return wordArray.join('');
}
```

I tried to change a little connectivity (between .js files),but it didn't work.
I'm a beginner in JavaScript so I'd be grateful for your advices and explains.